# Установка сеттеров для Element в QtWebkit

Tags: javascript, qt

Пытаюсь сделать свой сеттер для innerHTML:

```
var oldDescr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "innerHTML");

Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'innerHTML',
  {
    set: function(htmlVal)
      {
        document.write("CATCH!");
        oldDescr.set.call(this, htmlVal);
      }
  });

document.getElementById("foobar").innerHTML = "HEHE";
```

Все работает в FF 39, Chrome 43. Беру примеры из комплекта Qt 5.4 (browser/fancybrowser) - не вызывается мой сеттер. Как можно для QtWebkit сделать желаемое?

PS: это древний баг в WebKit, который, похоже, не пофиксили в QtWebkit: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13175

Comment: Вы можете добавить ссылку и описание проблемы, а возможно, и воркэраунды, если такие имеются, в качестве ответа.

Comment: @Discord судя по всему для QtWebkit проблема все еще актуальна.

Comment: Суть в том, что этот посткриптум технически является ответом на данный момент. Неприятным, но ответом.

Comment: А... ОК, сейчас тогда его в ответ перенесу.

Answer (score 1):

Это древний баг в WebKit, который, похоже, не пофиксили в QtWebkit: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13175

> All other browsers have a way to retrieve the native getters/setters for 
>   native properties. Consider these samples:
>
> ```
> HTMLDivElement.prototype.__lookupGetter__("innerHTML") // Firefox
> document.createElement("div").__lookupGetter__("innerHTML") // Firefox, Opera
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "innerHTML") // IE
> ```
>
> None of these work in Chrome/Webkit. Only custom getters/setters can be 
>   looked up.
>
> **What steps will reproduce the problem?**
>
> Use this testcase:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> alert(HTMLDivElement.prototype.__lookupGetter__("innerHTML"));
> </script>
> ```
>
> **What is the expected result?**
>
> The native setter/getter function of the property.
>
> **What happens instead?**
>
> `undefined` is returned.